# Java Question: is float not allowed to be declared as final?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Is declaring a variable using float as final not allowed in java?

(using JDK 1.8.0.201, by the way)

```
final float TESTVARIABLE = .5;
```

expected: float should be allowed, as I only need a memory space sized for a float

Error:

```
Required: float
Found:    double
```

Actual:

```
final double TESTVARIABLE = .5;
```

the double variable type works, but the float variable type does not.

> EDIT:
> this is asking about the error, and why the error is popping up.
>
> this is also asking whether the float could be declared as final.
>
> (this is just for those who are just starting java, and don't know how to fix
> errors that their CS teachers don't know how to fix.)
>
> (yes, i know that's repetitive, but that was the best way that I could think of >to explain it.)

*can you guys make a java-errors tag, so that this post could be more easily found?*

Comment: Try this: `final float TESTVARIABLE = .5f;`

Comment: Does it work *without* `final`? It also doesn't,  which suggests that probably `final` is not culprit here as result you get is same with or without it.

Comment: Sure. Read the answer below. `final` has nothing to do with the error you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `final`.  When you type `.5`, it is a `double` literal, but you're attempting to assign it to a `float`.  That is what causes the error.

```
float TESTVARIABLE = .5;  // error even without final
```

Place a [`f` or `F` suffix on the numeric literal to make it a `float` literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), decimal point or not.

> A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it ends with the letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is `double` and it can optionally end with the letter `D` or `d`.

```
final float TESTVARIABLE = .5f;
```